# Using FastDDS discovery server through SSH tunnel to remote PC

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got a Windows 10 notebook and a remote Linux PC.
I can connect to the Linux PC from Windows with SSH over VPN connection.
Linux PC is also behind a firewall, however, it is possible to open ports in it.

I'd like to use FastDDS discovery server to run ROS2 nodes on Windows and Linux.

Is it possible?
How should I configure firewall and SSH-tunnel?

I was following tutorial at https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Discovery-Server/Discovery-Server.html#run-this-tutorial

Current setup that is not working.

0. SSH and firewall configuration

   I use Putty for SSH, I add SSH tunnel to port 11811:localhost:11811

   UDP port range 42900 - 43000 is opened in the firewall.
1. Open SSH connection to Linux and run discovery server

   ```
    $ . /opt/ros2/foxy/local_setup.zsh
       $ export ROS2_DOMAIN_ID=142
    $ fastdds discovery --server-id 0
   ```
2. Open SSH connection to Linux and run listener node

   ```
    $ . /opt/ros2/foxy/local_setup.zsh
       $ export ROS2_DOMAIN_ID=142
    $ export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=127.0.0.1:11811
       $ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server
   ```
3. Open SSH connection to Linux and run talker node

   ```
    $ . /opt/ros2/foxy/local_setup.zsh
       $ export ROS2_DOMAIN_ID=142
    $ export ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=127.0.0.1:11811
       $ ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker --ros-args --remap __node:=talker_discovery_server
   ```

   And the listener prints "I heard [Hello world]"
4. Open new CMD terminal in windows and run another listener.

   ```
    c:\> call c:\opt\ros\foxy\local_setup.bat
    c:\> set ROS_DOMAIN_ID=142
    c:\> set ROS_DISCOVERY_SERVER=127.0.0.1:11811
    c:\> ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener --ros-args --remap __node:=listener_discovery_server
   ```

   And the Windows node doesn't hear "Hello"s

I've also tried running discovery server, talker and listener on Windows PC, and they do hear each other.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383029/using-fastdds-discovery-server-through-ssh-tunnel-to-remote-pc/) by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2021-07-23

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on 2021-07-23**:
Well, it looks like SSH tunnel can pass only TCP traffic, and ROS2 nodes are communicating over UDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not possible without additional software.

SSH tunnel passes TCP traffic, but ROS2 nodes are communicating over UDP.
Linux has `socat` or `netcat` programs that can help forwarding UDP traffic to SSH tunnel.
And it looks like there are no similar tools on Windows.

---

Originally posted by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) with karma: 127 on 2021-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-02**:
I'm not sure this is entirely correct.

Many DDS implementations allow you to configure TCP-based transports. FastDDS has a TCP/IP based transport for instance.

Whether that will make all functionality available I don't know, but that would be something to figure out.

Another option could be to use a (peer-to-peer) VPN. As you wrote, you can open ports in the firewall, so using something like [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/) should be possible (IIRC, it supports forwarding UDP). You'd be encapsulating UDP in TCP (so would lose all the advantages of UDP), but still.

**Comment by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on 2021-08-04**:
Unfortunately, I cannot use any VPN, this is not allowed in our company. I must use only one, specific, approved VPN.
I agree that I should better study documentation for DDS.
Yesterday I've managed to run talker and listener over our VPN following example from [this link](https://dds-demonstrators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Teams/1.Hurricane/DDSWan.html)
However, I had to switch from FastRTPS to CycloneDDS